Configure a non-Twilio number to CRM
I subscribed to a number from a local telco provider and completed the BYON process with Twilio Support. After testing, I successfully sent a WhatsApp message to the non-Twilio number and captured the message log in the Twilio console. My Meta Business Account also reflects the non-Twilio number.
From my understanding, all configurations for numbers are typically done on the "Active Number" page within the Twilio console. However, since this is not a Twilio number, it is not displayed on this page despite completing the BYON* procedure. I require this to connect the number to my CRM, so that all inbound messages will be captured and processed within the CRM platform.
I am concerned about how to perform the necessary configurations given this situation. Any assistance would be appreciated.
*BYON - Bring Your Own Number
I was informed by a Twilio Support (the BYON representative) that a "number porting" process would help reflect the non-Twilio number on the "Active Number" page. However, another Twilio Support (from the number porting team) informed me that this function is not available in my country. While I await further advice from the Twilio Support Team, I am seeking additional help here. My experience with Twilio over the past few months has been horrendous. Despite these terrible experiences, I am still required to use Twilio.
